# Hacking a LED fluorescent tube

Tags: led-strip, led-driver

I'm trying to hack a LED fluorescent tube and PWM it with arduino and a TIP120 transistor .
I bought one and disassembled it, basically it's an LED strip connected to a 220v though a LED driver.

I'm trying to bypassing the 220v LED driver, and power the LED strip directly from a DC power supply.
I started measuring the voltage on the LED strip when it's on and i got 18v on 2 points. 
however when I'm trying to power those 2 points directly with 18v from an external power source without the 220 LED driver i got nothing...

i [attached an image](http://s29.postimg.org/68bcgm22v/IMG_2938_Large_Large.jpg) of the LED strip connected to 220 LED driver...

Does anyone have an idea how can I bypass the 220 LED driver ?

[image]

Comment: Did you measure how much current was flowing?

Comment: How many LED's are on there? Can you trace out how these are connected? LED's usuallay don't like a voltage source, are there any other components on the strip except for the LED's?

Comment: 1. LED driver regulates current flowing through LEDs, not voltage. 2. Check connections (number of LEDs series/parallel) on strip, LED strips have very thin isolation so it is easy to re-draw how they are connected.

Comment: Ok I explored a little more and It's not a "regular" LED strip like I  know, this strip is from the same material of PCB, and the lines are PCB like. I sanded it a little bit and figure out that The LEDs are connected in a series and there are no components  except for LED's on the strip . I tried to power few are them with an 12V PC PSU and I managed to power 4 in the same time in and get a good luminosity, when I tried 5 got poor  luminosity. There's 120 LEDs on the strip and it's says 22W on the package. 
So what power supply do I need to use in order to control this led using an Arduino ?

Comment: Can you please confirm the total LED count? Did you say 120 LED's in series? Or was that a typo? Is the number of LED's, maybe 12?

Comment: I have a horrible suspiscion that your driver is not isolated .If  I am right then you will fry !  Dont get zapped .I hope you know what you are doing .

Answer (score 2):

Even though you saw 18 volts across the LEDs with your multi-meter, this does not necessarily mean that you can just put 18 volts across the LEDs and get the same result. LEDs are diodes (the D in LED) and so act a lot like a short when lit. Very small changes in voltage can result in very large changes in current, so it is not practical to drive LEDs with a constand voltage source. You can read more about it here...

https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/219

For a single LED, you can usually get away with just putting a resistor in series with the LED and then driving with a constant voltage source. This works because the voltage drop across the resistor will increase as the current though it (and the LED) increases.

You could potentially power your string from a fixed DC voltage by putting a resistor in series with it. You'd need to make sure that the resistor could handle the maximum power it might need to dissipate.

But to do it right, you will want probably want to use a constant current LED driver. The one you currently have converts a 220VAC input into a constant current output where the amount of current is configured to match the LED string. You can google "buck converter schematic" and "constant current LED driver" to get an idea of how that board works, but looking at the photo, it probably has these sections...

1. A rectifier that turns the incoming AC into DC.
2. A chopper that turns the rectified DC in high frequency pulses.
3. A transformer that turns the high voltage pulses into low voltage pulses.
4. A filtering cap that smooths the output pulses.
5. A a current sense resistor that is in series with the output current that converts the output current level into a voltage that is then used to adjust the width of the high voltage pulses to keep the output current at the desired level.

(Your board could be different in several ways - for example the sensing could happen on the high voltage side, or instead of a full rectifier you could only have a single diode to half rectify the incoming AC. you'll need to look at the board carefully and figure out what is happening).

I have had some luck with tricking boards like this to do my bidding with very little additional components. The jist is that you mess with the voltage that the pulse generator sees to trick it into decreasing the input duty cycle, which lowers the output current and dims or turns off the LEDs.

It is possible to use an arduino to control all this, but again it is dependent on the specific board you have.

Alternately, you can just buy an AC/DC dimmable constant current power supply pretty cheaply and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty certain (after looking inside a couple myself) that if you measure the voltage between LED+ and LED- (red and white wires), it'll be somewhere between 36 and 80v, depending on the way the LEDs are wired.  I am reasonably certain that neutral for the driver board comes all the way across the LED board via the black wire; it most likely does not connect to the LEDs themselves.

There may be 120 LEDs in series, but in one bulb I opened up, they were connected in 5 parallel groups of 24 LEDs in series, with a working voltage of 72v.  Boost converters can be found on eBay that can output 72vDC, and you could control the whole light with a (high voltage) transistor on the negative side of the LED.  TIP120 is a 60v transistor and will not work; preferably, you'd use at least a 100v transistor. (DC boost converter: http://www.ebay.com/itm/232304462432 for example; note that it has both voltage and current regulation adjustments.  It is WAY bigger than you need, but I'm not aware of smaller ones that can get the output voltage.)

Have fun, and be safe.  This is high voltage.

Comment: eBay links don't make good references, because eBay auctions expire and that information disappears.  Please edit your post and change the link to something permanent.